# PhpSpreadsheet is putting a number beside sheet label title

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

This is my code :-

```
$facilities = Facility::where('area_id','!=',1)->where('area_id','!=',4)->get();
        $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
        
        foreach($facilities as $i => $facility){
            
        $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex($i);
        $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

        $sheet->setTitle('test');
       
        if(($i+1) !== count($facilities)){
            $spreadsheet->createSheet();
        }
       
        }

        $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0);   
        $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
        $writer->save(base_path().'/tracking-file/test.xlsx');
```

The issue that i just put a title for each sheet with ('test'), the output is showing number beside the title:-
[image]

How can i remove these number from the label title?

Comment: I guess it's impossible for sheets to have duplicate titles so the API is adding a number at the end?

Comment: @Jeto you are totally right, can you post as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [the docs on adding a new Worksheet](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/worksheets/#adding-a-new-worksheet):

> A new worksheet created using this method will be called `Worksheet<n>`
> where `<n>` is the lowest number possible to guarantee that the title is
> unique.

The same behavior can be found in [`Worksheet::setTitle`'s source code](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/blob/master/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Worksheet/Worksheet.php#L861).